# beaglebone black insmod modprobe g_mass_storage did NOT work

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, insmod

How to insert module `g_mass_storage.ko`?

It is located at `/lib/modules/3.8.6/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/` with -rw-r--r-- permissions.

```
# insmod g_mass_storage.ko
```

**Output:** *Error: could not load module g_mass_storage.ko: No such file or directory*

```
# modprobe g_mass_storage.ko
```

**Output:** *FATAL: Module g_mass_storage.ko not found.*

How do we fix this?

`# uname -a`

**Output:** Linux beaglebone 3.8.6 #1 SMP Sat Apr 13 09:10:52 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Thanking you @Milind, I have updated in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered that there is `g_multi` module that is conflicting with `g_mass_storage`
`rmmod g_multi` allowed to insert `g_mass_storage`.

However, `g_multi` solves the purpose of `g_mass_storage`.
This worked:
`# modprobe g_multi file=/tmp/auto_storage removable=y`

Comment: g_multi provides as many functions as allowed to have endpoints on device gadget. In newer kernel you may find configfs which is supposed to help configure functions of the gadget device at run time.